# Amazon Mobile Hub vs a custom backend vs Parse

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, parsing, mobile, backend

My app was built using Parse as a backend. My understanding is that the plug-and-play architecture of Parse is limiting - that the services layer that should be used for business logic doesn't exist or is limited. Now I'm debating whether to build a custom backend or to use Amazon Mobile Hub. My concern though is that if I chose Amazon Mobile Hub I will run into the same services layer issues I experienced with Parse.

I'm wondering if my assumption is correct: does Amazon Mobile Hub have a non-existent or limited services layer?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try AWS Amplify https://aws-amplify.github.io/